# Чтение из TextEdit и ответ на введённый текст

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

Как сделать так, чтобы если в **TextEdit** было введено "*Meow*" в TextView должен появиться ответ "*Wow*"
Заранее спасибо, просьба ни минусить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Минус не мой, хотя готовтесь :) это азы которые есть в любой книжке

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements TextWatcher {
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
         textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
         editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
          }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if(charSequence.toString().equals("Meow")) textView.setText("Wow");
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Кросава!!!)))))